# Compare ListBox and list then print to Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a `ListBox` that stores items such as camping gear. The `ListBox` will have tent, camping chairs, coffee and so on.
Then I created a list that has the prices for each item called `lstprices`.

When I double click on the entry it will appear in another `ListBox` while pulling the price from the `lstprices` and add it to a `subtotal` `Label`.

```
try
{
    if (lstItems.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        lstOrder.Items.Add(lstItems.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am assuming I would somehow add information to the `lstOrder.Items` since I know the element numbers but don't understand how to display it in my `Label`.
I hope this makes sense.

Also for this statement:

```
decimal STotal = decimal.Parse(lblSubtotal.Text.ToString());
```

it errors stating that its in the wrong format when I double click the item.

Comment: If you're trying to store multiple fields for multiple records you will be much better off using a [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms) than a list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot comment so have to post an answer:

if you have to keep track of multiple properties of an object then you should create a class of it for example (Object Oriented Programming):

```
public class Product 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}

    public Product(string name, double price) 
    {
       Name = name;
       Price = price
    }
}
```

this way you can just do: `Product chair = new Product("Camping Chair", 12.99);`
or you can fill a list

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
                         {
                          new Product("Camping Chair", 12.99),
                          new Product("Tent", 25.99)
                         }
```

and then display your products in a list or datagridview etc. it will be a better approach then maintaining two lists with names and prices.

this will also make work with the listbox easier it has a property called `SelectedItem` which you can cast to your class and then reference it properties for example:

```
    Product selectedProduct = myListbox.SelectedItem as Product;
    myLabel.Text = selectedProduct?.Price.ToString();
```

---

EDIT:

since classes have not been covered by, what you can do is use a  `Dictionary<string,double>` to keep track of your prices and keys (product name) or at least a  `List<KeyValuePair<string,double>>` :

Below a quick example to get you started:

```
 Dictionary<string, double> products = new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            {"Camping Chair",33.0},
            {"Stool",12.99},
        };
 //accessing the price via the key, which 
 var price = products.Where(x => x.Key == "Stool").SingleOrDefault();

 // you could then pass in the selected item of your list box as string
 var price = products.Where(x => x.Key == listbox.SelectedItem.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();
```

More about [dictionary at msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

More about [KeyValuePair at msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I have not learned about classes yet so I do not think that that will help me out. So far this is what i currently have for my code

Comment: and what about structs or at least dictionaries? Hmm to be honest, you shouldn't work with GUI's yet if you haven't covered classes and (potential other) fundamentals.